# In ClearQuest, How do I generate a query in SQL Editor that allows me to prompt the user for a value?

Tags: sql, clearquest

I generate a ClearQuest query using the Query Wizard. In the Query Editor, I am able to select a filter for a given field. However, I want to refine the query using the SQL Editor, but then I loose the ability to have a dynamic filter. How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure the answer is "you can't" since the SQL generated includes the value entered for any dynamic filters set up when you built the query, and as you say, the act of editing the SQL prevents using the Query Editor to make further changes.

Your best bet is to figure out a way to use the Query Editor to do what you need the SQL Editor for. Start another question.